# Router showing established connection between 2 external IP's

Tags: router

I have been getting weird network issues on my ADSL router the last few days, seemingly getting flooded.

My ISP-assigned IP is `105.x.x.x`.

I have noted the following entries in `ip_conntrack`:

```
tcp 6   359405  ESTABLISHED src=10.196.65.25    dst=173.194.70.188  sport=36444 dport=5228  [UNREPLIED] src=173.194.70.188  dst=10.196.65.25    sport=5228  dport=36444 use=2
tcp 6   426547  ESTABLISHED src=197.71.78.221   dst=74.125.233.87   sport=33318 dport=443   [UNREPLIED] src=74.125.233.87   dst=197.71.78.221   sport=443   dport=33318 use=2
tcp 6   362658  ESTABLISHED src=41.5.152.197    dst=69.171.245.49   sport=58660 dport=443   [UNREPLIED] src=69.171.245.49   dst=41.5.152.197    sport=443   dport=58660 use=2
```

The destinations seems to point to Google and Facebook, and the sources are unreachable from me.

Why would this appear on my router?

Why would a private network IP appear there? (My local network is `192.168.1.0/24`). Also a trace to `197.71.78.221` shows it going over some routers in the `10.0.0.0/8` range.

Is this due to wrongly configured routers on my ISP and/or their backbone?

Sorry if these questions are stupid :)

(I have forwarded the info to my ISP, but still awaiting a response).

Comment: The `[UNREPLIED]` strongly indicates that these entries are crap coming from some kind of botnet style traffic.

Comment: @Zoredache: Thanks, I did not know that :)